# Call UWP AppService on winform/wpf client

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windows-services, uwp

When i call AppService on UWP app, the AppServiceConnectionStatus returns Success.
But, when i call AppService on winform or wpf client, the AppServiceConnectionStatus still return AppServiceUnavailable.
UWP,Winform,WPF,the client code are the same:

```
private AppServiceConnection appService;
private async void ConnectServer()
{
    if (appService == null)
    {
        appService = new AppServiceConnection();
        appService.AppServiceName = "AserSecurityService";
        appService.PackageFamilyName = "AserSecurityService_gfeg8w3smza92";

        var status = await this.appService.OpenAsync();
        if (status != AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
        {
            appService = null;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The service code below:

```
public sealed class AserSecurityComponentProviderTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral backgroundTaskDeferral;
    private AppServiceConnection appServiceconnection;

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        this.backgroundTaskDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        taskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskCanceled;

        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
        appServiceconnection = details.AppServiceConnection;
        appServiceconnection.RequestReceived += OnRequestReceived;
    }

    private async void OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var requestDeferral = args.GetDeferral();

        try
        {
            var message = args.Request.Message;

            var result = new ValueSet();

            if (message.ContainsKey("HardwareID"))
            {
                result.Add("HardwareID", GetHardwareID());
            }

            await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var result = new ValueSet();

            result.Add("exception", ex);

            await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(result);
        }
        finally
        {
            requestDeferral.Complete();
        }
    }

    private void OnTaskCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        if (this.backgroundTaskDeferral != null)
        {
            this.backgroundTaskDeferral.Complete();
        }
    }

    private string GetHardwareID()
    {
        if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification"))
        {
            var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
            var hardwareId = token.Id;
            var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
            dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

            return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
        }

        throw new Exception("NO API FOR DEVICE ID PRESENT!");
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

or you can download my sample project code zip from
[here](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1slrcPrv) or [otherLink](https://setup.aserweb.com/AppServiceSample.zip).

Comment: Well nobody will download a zip file an open it, I hope you understand why?! So without providing a minimal compile-able example, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Lol this does'nt change anything. But keep going!

Comment: I tested your sample with your second Link, three apps all works fine by my side, the ConnectionStatus returns Success. Is that possible your service was killed when you tested your winform app and wpf app?

Comment: First, i start the service project, then start all the client side at the same time, the UWP client connect success, winform/wpf client still return AppServiceUnavailable

Comment: On my machine, winform/wpf client can not connect success. I run the project on the other machine, it all work find, I don't know why.

Comment: What's your OS version? My OS version is 10586.

Comment: My OS version is 10586, i develop this on the other machine, it work find.
I also want to launch the appservice app on winform. how can I make the app run on background and don't show the app window?